# Flexible Store/Grid

Tags: extjs6

I have the follow problem: I need to consume a REST service (3rd party, not mine) and show the result data to the user using an `Ext.grid.Panel`.

The problem is I have no idea of the data structure and content ( it is a JSON from Geoserver's `queryLayer` ) so I can't have a store/grid/model field definition to respect the ExtJS MVC design.

So how can I be more flexible in this situation? I try to add a row to the grid `by hand` but after read https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?48625-how-can-i-insert-a-row-in-GRID I think it is a kind of crime to do

Answer (score 0):

You can add a conversion layer for dynamic fields in the model class. The conversion will provide a string readable format for data you don't know the structure.

```
Ext.define('AppName.DynamicRow', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [{
        name: 'fixed1',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'fixed2',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'dynamic',
        type: 'string',
        calculate: function (data) {
            Ext.Object.getAllKeys(data)
                .map(function(key) {
                    return key + ': ' + data[key];
                })
                .join(', ');
        }
    }]
});
```

Then you will show all unstructured data in a grid column simply adding 'dynamic' field as dataIndex.

Comment: I don't think this it is a good idea... I need a grid to show the data as a grid! Don't want to throw all my data in a column.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:

First, receive the data using a function to concentrate all creation stuff:

```
function addGrid ( title, data ) {
    var storeColumns = getStoreColumnsFromJson( data[0] );   
    var gridColumns = getGridColumnsFromJson( data[0] );

    var store = createStore( data, storeColumns );
    var grid = createGrid( title, store, gridColumns );

    myContainerWindowPanel.add( grid );

}
```

Now, I need to take a data sample (first row) to get the column names from the JSON data to the grid and its store:

```
function getStoreColumnsFromJson ( obj ) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            keys.push({name : key});
        }
    }
    return keys;    
}

function getGridColumnsFromJson ( obj ) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            keys.push({text: key, dataIndex: key});
        }
    }
    return keys;    
}
```

Now I'll create the grid and the store. I will not use the Model simply because this worked without it. If someone have a strong advice to create the model I'll appreciate.

```
function createGrid ( title, store, columnNames ) {
    var dummyGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        border: false,
        title : title,
        store : store,
        frame: false,
        margin: "10 0 0 0", 
        flex:1,
        loadMask: true,
        columns:columnNames,
        autoHeight:true
    });
    return dummyGrid;
}

function createStore ( storeData, columns ) {
    var arrData = [];
    var theData = storeData;
    if ( !$.isArray( storeData ) ) {
        arrData.push( storeData );
        theData = arrData;
    } 

    var store =  Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
        fields: columns,
        autoLoad: true,
        data: theData
    });     
    return store;
}
```